# How is the remUnit option in px2rem configured?

Tags: css

I use px2rem-loader and hotcss for mobile adaptation，I read the official documents, but I still don't understand how the remUnit of px2rem is configured。

I try to set remUnit to 80 and div with 640px width in css. The div automatically converted to REM is exactly half of the total width.I tried to set remUnit to 93.75, and set the width of a div half of the screen in CSS to 750px.I'd like to know how this remUnit works. How do I configure it?

```
webpack.config.js：
{loader: 'px2rem-loader',
  options: {
  remUnit : 80,
  remPrecision: 8
                }
  },

css:
.aaa{width: 640px;height: 640px;float: left;box-sizing: border-box;border: 1px solid red;}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about px2rem, but according to my Google search, the default dpr (device pixel ratio) is 2, so you might need to either put `dpr:1` in your config, or run the tool with `px2rem -b 1`. See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/px2rem#cli-tool).